# Calculation of integral involving Sum

Tags: functions, numerical-integration, summation

My code is the following:

```
w[2] = 0.2;
w[3] = 0.4;

r[x_, t_] := (2/3)*(Sum[(Sin[k*x*Pi])^2, {k, 1, 3}] + 2*Sin[Pi*x]*Sum[Sin[j*Pi*x]*Cos[w[j]*t], 
{j, 2, 3}] + 2*Sin[2*Pi*x]*Sin[3*Pi*x]*Cos[-2.5*Pi^2]*t)

F[t_] := NIntegrate[(D[r[x, t], x])^2/r[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "DoubleExponential", 
WorkingPrecision -> 16, AccuracyGoal -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 16]

ListPlot[Table[{t, F[t]}, {t, 0, 50}]]
```

I think that something is going wrong with the differentiation. Any ideas?

Comment: The integrand `Derivative[1, 0][r][x, t] ^2/r[x, t]` shows holes in the plot `Plot3D[Derivative[1, 0][r][x, t] ^2/r[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thank you! But what does it mean? How could I overcome these holes?

Comment: There are singularities (vanishing denominator)  :` ContourPlot[(3 (Sin[\[Pi] x]^2 + Sin[2 \[Pi] x]^2 + 
      2 t Cos[(5 \[Pi]^2)/2] Sin[2 \[Pi] x] Sin[3 \[Pi] x] + 
      Sin[3 \[Pi] x]^2 + 
      2 Sin[\[Pi] x] (Cos[t/5] Sin[2 \[Pi] x] + 
         Cos[(2 t)/5] Sin[3 \[Pi] x]))) == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]` If you are able to calculate these singularities, you can use the option `Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {x==...}` inside NIntegrate.